# Laravel 7 : How to show single image on blade view when i have multiple images/path stored in database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I don't know my logic is wrong or I am doing something wrong.

I have a page "all-business" where I am showing all businesses on a page. when someone clicks on a single business it will go to the "business-details" page. Now what I want to do is showing single image on the all-business page. and when someone clicks on a single business than I want to show multiple images on the business-details page. here is my code

Business Model

```
class Business extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [''];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function subCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategory');
    }

    public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Province');
    }
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
}
```

controller

```
public function allBusinesses()
    {
        $businesses = Business::paginate(5);
        return view('front-end.buy-business', compact('businesses'));
    }
```

blade

```
    <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        @foreach ($businesses as $business)
                        {{-- {{dd($business)}} --}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="" class="d-block text-reset box-anchor">
                                <div class="box-outer">
                                    <div class="box-inner">
                                       <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$business->image)}}" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                                        <hr />
                                        <hr />
                                        <h2 class="text-black-50">{{$business->price}} <span
                                                class="text-small">Pkr</span></h2>
                                        <p class="box-inner-p">{{$business->name}}</p>

                                        <div class="box-bottom">
                                            <span class="box-bottom-left">{{$business->user->name}}</span>
                                            <span class="box-bottom-right">location</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
```

if you want more details just comment thankyou :)

Comment: post the Business model

Comment: @Berto99 check i update the post.

Comment: `{{asset('storage/'.in_array('$business->image[1]'))}}` looks completely wrong. What is `in_array()` doing in there? And `'$business->image[1]'` will not expand `$business->image[1]` because of the single quotes.

Comment: I didnt create any Image model

Comment: @kerbh0lz I find something on the internet so i did copy and paste. which is not working for me :)

Comment: if you want your business to have multiple images, you need to create a model/table for business_images for example, there to store the path and the business id, and so to have a 1 to  N  relations

Comment: @Berto99 okhy. let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will edit your business model so it can actually have several images (like Berto99 said in his comment), what I would do then in the views is something like this:

```blade
@forelse ($business->images as $image)
    <img src="{{asset($image)}}" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
    @break
@empty
    {{-- If for some reason the business has no images, you can put here some kind of placeholder image, using 3rd party services or maybe your own generic image --}}
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
@endforelse
```

for the **all-business** view. Then you can use almost the same block of code in your **business-details** view, you just need to get rid of the `@break` sentence so it shows all images instead of only one.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna show just one image you can use in foreach

```
@if ($loop->first)
    This is the first iteration.
@endif
```

If you wanna just show show first image in all loop

```
$business[0]image[1]
```

You can use index